# Código en Java con arrayList y herencia

Tags: java, arraylist, herencia

Disculpas por la pregunta, puede ser muy tonta, pero debo entregarlo pronto y no consigo realizarlo.
Debo realizar un programa en java que use arrayList y herencia.
Se trata de una clínica veterinaria que debe guardar en el arrayList: Nombre, Peso, Edad y tipo de animal (Perro o gato). Y pide usar herencia.

Creé una clase Animal con esos atributos principales, y creé 3 clases hijas (perro y gato) cada una con atríbutos propios. Perro suma el atributo String Pedigree, Gato suma el atributo String Color.

Clase Métodos

```
public class Métodos {
    public int op, opcion;
    public Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
    public ArrayList <Animal> lista = new ArrayList <Animal> ();
    public boolean res;
    
    public void menu (){
        System.out.println("1.Agregar");
        System.out.println("2.Listar");
        System.out.println("3.Buscar");
        System.out.println("4.Eliminar");
        System.out.println("5.Salir");
        System.out.println("Elija la opción: ");
        op = teclado.nextInt();
        switch(op){
            case 1: 
                agregar();
                break;
            case 2: break;
            case 3: break;
            case 4: break;
            case 5: 
                salir();
                break;
            default: 
                errorOpcion();
                break;
        } 
    }
    public void agregar () {
        
        System.out.println("1.Perro");
        System.out.println("2.Gato");
        System.out.println("3.Ave");
        System.out.println("Elija la opción: ");
        opcion = teclado.nextInt();
        
        switch (opcion){
            case 1: perro(); 
                    break;
                    default:
                        break;
        }
    }
        public void perro (String nombre, int edad, float peso, int codigo, String pedigree, String razaPerro){
            
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre:");
        nombre=teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el peso:");
        peso=teclado.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la edad:");
        edad=teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la raza del perro:");
        razaPerro=teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el alimento del perro:");
        pedigree=teclado.nextLine();
        
        p = new perro();
        p.setCodigo(codigo);
        p.setNombre(nombre);
        p.setPeso(peso);
        p.setEdad(edad);
        p.setRazaPerro(razaPerro);
        p.setPedigree(pedigree);
        lista.add(p);
        
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("--------REGISTRO GUARDADO---------");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        
        menu();
    }
     
    public void salir () {
        System.out.println("\nPrograma finalizado");
        System.exit(0);
    } //cierra método salir
    
    public void errorOpcion (){
        System.out.println("\nOpción incorrecta");
        menu();
    }// cierra el switch
}
```

Clase Animal

```
public class Animal {
    public String nombre;
    public float peso;
    public int edad;

    public Animal(String nombre, float peso, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.edad = edad;
    }



    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public float getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }

    public void setPeso(float peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
}
```

Clase Perro

```
public class Perro extends Animal{
    public String Pedigree;
    
    public Perro(String Pedigree, String nombre, float peso, int edad) {
        super(nombre, peso, edad);
        this.Pedigree = Pedigree;
    }

    public String getPedigree() {
        return Pedigree;
    }

    public void setPedigree(String Pedigree) {
        this.Pedigree = Pedigree;
    }

 }
```

Lo que no sé es si debo usar un switch para la carga del arrayList donde se indique si se va a cargar perro o gato, o cómo se debe implementar la carga de 2 clases distintas que tiene atributos distintos, no creo que se deba repetir la carga de los atributos comunes a Animal en cada clase Perro y Gato.

Puse todo public porque se me había complicado acceder a los atributos.

Sí, lo sé, es un desastre el código, y además me falta la clase principal.

Supongo que es un programa fácil de hacer pero no nos explicaron bien el tema y tengo 3 días para hacerlo.
Desde ya muchas gracias a quien responda.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo q has intentado para recibir ayuda

Comment: Te dejaría el código pero mejor te dejo para que revises el siguiente enlace de [Herencia en java](https://jarroba.com/herencia-en-la-programacion-orientada-a-objetos-ejemplo-en-java/)

Answer (score 1):

Te faltaría adicionar una clase veterinaria donde inicialices el arrayList ,y donde tengas un método que registre instancia de tipo Animal() sean perros,gatos etc. para obtener los datos propios y heredados puedes crear un método listar datos() en la clase padre y adicionar los datos propios de las hijas,de la siguiente manera...

CLASE PERRO

```
public Perro(String nombre,String codigo,float peso, int edad,String pedigree,String raza){
  super(nombre,codigo, peso, edad);
  this.pedigree=pedigree;
  this.raza=raza;

 }

 public String listarDatos(){
 return super.listarDatos()+"\nPedigree: "+pedigree+"\nRaza: "+raza+"\n"; 
 }
  
 public String getRaza() {
     return raza;
 }
  
 public void setRaza(String raza) {
     this.raza = raza;
 }
  
 public String getPedigree() {
     return pedigree;
 }
  
 public void setPedigree(String pedigree) {
     this.pedigree = pedigree;
 }
```

CLASE GATO

```
public class Gato extends Animal{
    public String color;

    
    public Gato(String nombre,String codigo,float peso, int edad,String color) {
        super(nombre,codigo, peso, edad);
        this.color = color;
    }


    public String listarDatos(){
      return super.listarDatos()+"\nColor: "+color+"\n";
    } 

    public String getcolor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setcolor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

 }
```

CLASE ANIMAL(PADRE)

```
public class Animal {
    public String nombre;
    public String codigo;
    public float peso;
    public int edad;

    public Animal(String nombre,String codigo,float peso, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.codigo=codigo;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String listarDatos(){
     return "\nAnimal: "+this.getClass().getSimpleName()+"\nNombre: "+nombre+"\nCodigo: "+codigo+"\nPeso: "+peso+"\nEdad: "+edad;
    }

     public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }


     
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public float getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }

    public void setPeso(float peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
}
```

Lo siguiente es la clase veterinaria donde tendrás tus métodos  registro,listado total,buscar etc si quieres acceder a una clase en especifico  te sugiero usar (instanceof) por si quieres listar solo datos de gatos o perros

CLASE VETERINARIA

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Veterinaria{

//METODOS
private List<Animal>lista;

public Veterinaria(){
  lista=new ArrayList<>();
}

public void  registrar(Animal a){
  lista.add(a);
}

public List<Animal> getLista(){
    return lista;
}



//MENU

static Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
static Veterinaria veterinaria1=new Veterinaria(); 

public static void salir () {
        System.out.println("\nPrograma finalizado");
        System.exit(0);
    }   

public static void errorOpcion (){
        System.out.println("\nOpción incorrecta");
        menu();
    }

public static void listar(){
  for(Animal a:veterinaria1.getLista()){
     System.out.println(a.listarDatos());
  }
 }  
      
public static void menu (){
        System.out.println("1.Agregar");
        System.out.println("2.Listar");
        System.out.println("3.Buscar");
        System.out.println("4.Eliminar");
        System.out.println("5.Salir");
        System.out.println("Elija la opción: ");
        int op = teclado.nextInt();
        switch(op){
            case 1: 
                agregar();
                break;
            case 2:
                listar();
                menu();
             break;
            case 3: break;
            case 4: break;
            case 5: 
                salir();
                break;
            default: 
                errorOpcion();
                break;
        } 
    }

    public static void agregar () {
        
        System.out.println("1.Perro");
        System.out.println("2.Gato");
        System.out.println("3.Ave");
        System.out.println("Elija la opción: ");
        int opcion = teclado.nextInt();
        
        switch (opcion){
            case 1: perro(); 
                    break;
            case 2: gato();
                    break;        
                    default:
                        break;
        }
    }

public static void perro(){

    System.out.println("\nSECCION PERROS\n");   
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre:");
    String nombre=teclado.next();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el codigo");
    String codigo=teclado.next();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el peso:");
    Float peso=teclado.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Ingrese la edad:");
    int edad=teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese la raza del perro:");
    String raza=teclado.next();
    System.out.println("Tiene Pedigree? (si/no):");
    String pedigree=teclado.next();
    Perro p =new Perro(nombre,codigo,peso,edad,pedigree,raza) ;
    veterinaria1.registrar(p);
        
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
    System.out.println("--------REGISTRO GUARDADO---------");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
    menu();
   }

   public static void gato(){

    System.out.println("\nSECCION GATOS\n");   
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre:");
    String nombre=teclado.next();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el codigo");
    String codigo=teclado.next();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el peso:");
    Float peso=teclado.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Ingrese la edad:");
    int edad=teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el color del gato:");
    String color=teclado.next();
    Gato g =new Gato(nombre,codigo,peso,edad,color) ;
    veterinaria1.registrar(g);
        
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
    System.out.println("--------REGISTRO GUARDADO---------");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
    menu();
   }


}
```

lo demas es que le agreges las funcionalidades que le falta y si quieres mas animales ,espero y te ayude en tu proceso.Ten presente que en POO los atrubtos de clases hijas y padre deber ser con acceso private.

Para poder copilarlo hazlo mediante otra clase con metodo main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {     
  
    Veterinaria veterinaria1=new Veterinaria();
    veterinaria1.menu();
 

     
 
}}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Me salvaste la vida. Trabajo y estudio y no me iba a dar el tiempo para corregirlo hasta mañana. Y sí, una de las consignas es contar cuantos animales hay de cada clase, y vi que hay que usar instanceof. Eso ya lo veré por mi cuenta. Muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: si la respuesta te sirvio valorala como util (flecha arriba) saludos cordiales